# The method CompareTo(String) is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, arrays

the following should allow user to input part of description (i.e. second in array) and if like the name of the toy, return the Title.

Any guidance appreciated.

Array sample:-
`a[0] = new Toy("001", "Ball"); 
               a[1] = new Toy("002", "Robot");`

```
                'case 'Search':
                String toySearch;
                System.out.print("Enter description: ");
                toySearch = sc.nextLine();                  

            {
                if (toySearch.length() == 0) {
                    done = true;

                } else

                {
                    // find matching toy description against user input
                    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) 
                    {
                                                if(inventory[i].getproductDesc().compareTo(toySearch))
                        {
                            done = false;
                        }

                        {
                            System.out.println(inventory[i].getproductDesc());
                        }
                        break;
                    }'
```

Comment: Replace `compareTo` with `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using User defined Class for inventory or any other object then you must override the *compareTo()* method of *java.lang* package.
- for Overriding *compareTo()* you need to implement *Comparable interface*.

Comment: Presumably the result of `getProductDesc()` is a `String`, so there's no need to override that method (which you can't anyway).

Answer (score -1):

You're using `compareTo` as if it returned a `boolean` value. It does not. Per the documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T- returns an `int`, which doesn't work as an `if` condition. You have to check whether `compareTo` returned "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer", per the documentation.

Comment: Unless `getProductDesc()` doesn't return a `String`, I fail to see the problem with this answer. Please explain the downvote so that I might learn.